# Increasing inner loop distance function with cupy

Tags: python, loops, cuda, gpu, cupy

I am trying to increase the speed of computation of a given distance function - c(x, y) while iterating of a inner loop array. I was trying to use cupy and benchmark with random values. So far I have the following code:

```
import time
import contextlib
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np

squared_diff = cp.ElementwiseKernel(
    'float64 x, float64 y',
    'float64 z',
    'z = (x - y) * (x - y)',
    'squared_diff')

 x, y = np.random.randn(1000), np.random.randn(1000)
 x_gpu, y_gpu = cp.random.randn(1000), cp.random.randn(1000)

 c = np.zeros((len(x), len(y)))
 c_gpu = cp.zeros((len(x), len(y)))


 @contextlib.contextmanager
 def timer(message):
     cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
     start = time.time()
     yield
     cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
     end = time.time()
     print('%s:  %f sec' % (message, end - start))


with timer(' CPU '):
     for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            c[i, j] = (x[i] - y[i]) ** 2

with timer(' GPU '):
     for i in range(len(x)):
         for j in range(len(y)):
            c_gpu[i, j] = squared_diff(x_gpu[i], y_gpu[j])
```

However, it seems the GPU time is significant higher in comparison with CPU.

```
CPU :  0.486763 sec
GPU :  26.627597 sec
```

Is there any significant hint or issue I am missing in considerating the theory behind increase computation speed with CUDA?

Comment: If I read that code correctly (and I didn't even know what cupy was until I googled for it 60 seconds ago), aren't you effectively calling that elementwise kernel 1000000 times with a single element in each call? If so, that absolutely isn't a remotely sane way to use the GPU

Comment: @talonmies: thanks for your reply. I am trying to look for a solution and I think I can agree with you on this. It seems that is the major overhead. Do you have any suggestions how can I improve performance on this case? It seems this operation should be parallelized as all the "cells" are independent of each other.

Comment: I also just noticed that your GPU and CPU version do not do the same operation either

Comment: @talonmies: could you elaborate on that? The operation seems pretty similar to me.

Comment: pretty similar isn't the same. Look carefully at the host code

Answer (score 3):

You need to broadcast input arrays to make it element-wise computation.

```
def bcast(x, y, xp):
    return (xp.broadcast_to(x[:, None], (1000, 1000)),
            xp.broadcast_to(y, (1000, 1000)))

x, y = bcast(x, y, np)
with timer(' CPU '):
    c = (x - y) ** 2

x_gpu, y_gpu = bcast(x_gpu, y_gpu, cp)
with timer(' GPU '):
    c_gpu2 = squared_diff(x_gpu, y_gpu)
```